# Ball inside an accelerating frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, inertia

Why does a ball inside a moving bus at rest start moving backwards when the bus suddenly accelerates? Also does the moving ball have some acceleration?

This is my theory:
Initially the bus and the ball are at rest. When the bus starts accelerating, due to inertia of rest, the ball resists change in motion and tends to remain at rest. Since it is an accelerating frame, pseudo forces of unknown origin act on the ball in the direction opposite to the direction of motion of the bus. This pseudo force is responsible for the ball to move in the opposite direction with some acceleration. This explanation with respect to the accelerating frame.

But how do I explain this fact from the frame of reference of a person on the road? I understand that the acceleration of the ball is in the same direction as that of acceleration of bus. There is no other force to balance this force which is in the direction of motion of bus. So the ball should have moved in a direction along the direction of the bus. But the reverse happens. Please help me.
[image]

Comment: From the non inertial frame its the pseudo force. From the inertial its inertia

Comment: If you neglect friction ball wont move unless it hits the back of the bus and gets dragged

Comment: You answered your question. There is nothing left to answer. Your theory is correct.

Comment: By the way Pseudo forces are as real as imaginary numbers are real !!

Comment: What makes you say that Shashank?

Comment: @AdityaDS  because both are . Just as there is an equivalence between gravity & acceleration . Gravity is real. And there is nothing Imaginary about imaginary numbers . They are as real as 1 ,2 ,100...

Comment: In the last line what do you mean by "the reverse happens"? If there is friction then relative to the road the ball does move in the direction of the moving bus, although relative to the bus it rolls backwards.

Comment: @sammy gerbil with respect to the road, the ball  should have moved along the directionoff the bus. It is evident from the figure. But in reality the ball moves in the opposite direction of the Bus. So how do you explain this with the road's frame of reference?

Comment: @sammy gerbil for an observer on the road he very clearly sees that ball and the bus move in opposite directions

Comment: The ball does not move backwards faster than the bus moves forwards. 
From the road frame of reference, they move in the same direction.

Comment: @JML Carter but what do you have to say about the figure that I have attached? Clearly from the road's frame the ball should have moved along the bus

Comment: Think of it as the bus moving alopng beneath the ball. Does that help?

Comment: What about friction?

Comment: I understand what everyone is trying to tell And I completely understand shashanks Answer. But i want someone to explain it taking friction into account

Comment: @AdityaDS You are making it confusing. You haven't mentioned friction anywhere in your question. If there is no friction then from the ground frame its acceleration is 0. The answer I have given is ok. If there is friction then check the edit I have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyse it this way .

If the bus is infinitely long such that there is no force from the walls and there is no friction also. Then in the road frame the ball stays where it is ( because no force acts on it ) while the bus moves forward.

In the bus frame the bus is at rest while to the bus the ball accelerates back which you have explained by the pseudo force .

Friction enters then rolling enters the scene sort of complicating the scene .

If there is Friction

Let u be the coefficient of friction then

From ground frame the FBD of the ball is

f=uN=ma towards the right.

From accelerated bus frame

f=uN=m(a+A) (towards the left)
mA being the pseudo force

Comment: Why don't you take friction into account and explain it? Yours is an ideal case. I want an explanation that fits in the real world

Comment: @AdityaDS  because what Sammy gerbil said for the real case is right

Comment: Didn't you read my next two comments?

Comment: @AdityaDS There is nothing to explain . What he said is precise and right and it's already explained I guess. How can I force to imagine that. You need to analyse the situation more yourself understand it . If friction acts on the ball has to accelerate with the bus .

Answer (score 0):

Take it like this imagine yourself as an by stander watching the bus then you would notice the ball goes in the direction opposite to bus but when we only take the ball the direction of pseudo force is opposite to the motion of the bus when we consider the floor to have friction then this $μN$ force to opposethis pesudo force hence the real motion occurs in the opposite direction of bus.while considering the consequences the motion of ball by the by stander is same as the one in the bus watching the ball.